# how to use Socket.IO in mobilefirst hybrid application?

Tags: socket.io, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm using **MobileFirst 7.1** mobile app development environment.

I would like to create new chat application without GCM and FCM. But I would like to use **Socket.IO**. Is there any way to create like this application in **Mobilefirst 7.1** kindly suggest me...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recommendations website...

I do not see any existing implementations of socket.io with MobileFirst, so I think you will simply have to try and following their docs and see if it works for you.